# alignment issue nested ordered list containing containing different font size

Tags: html, css

im trying to create list in html/css like below

```
1. Heading
1. content one
2. content two
3. content three

2. Heading
1. content one
2. content two
3. content three
```

and so on..

the font size of the heading and content (including number) are different

my problem is that i can't get the nested child list to align with the parent list.  it works when the fond-sizes are the same, but when i change it, the alignment changes as well.

anyone got any ideas on how i can best achieve this?

this is the html css i have so far

```
<style>
 ol {
    list-style: decimal;
    margin: 30px 0 0 30px; 
}
ol li {
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 20px; 
}
 ol li h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px; 
}
ol li ol {
    margin: 0 0 0 0; 
}
ol li ol li {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;    
    font-size: 15px; 
}
ol li ol li p{
    font-size: 15px;
}
 </style>

<ol>        
    <li>
        <h2>Heading 1</h2>          
        <ol>
            <li>
                <p>content 1</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>content 2</p>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>          
        <ol>
            <li>
                <p>content 1</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>content 2</p>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Please show an example with your HTML/CSS.

Comment: You should specify what browser you tested with.

Answer (score 0):

Just alter the `margin-left` or `padding-left` of `ol li ol`. Try different values until you get the desired result.

http://jsfiddle.net/LyrsY/ (However, jsFiddle uses a CSS reset that may give a different appearance than your page.)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code:

```
ol {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;   
}
```

Comment: this align the content nicely, but not the numbers

Answer (score 0):

As per i understand that's you want . 
Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ZHLKy/

```
 ol {
    list-style: decimal inside;
}
```

**UPDATED**

give margin to `ol li ol` & margin-left to your P like this:

```
ol li ol {
    margin: 0 0 0 1px;
}

ol li ol li p{
    font-size: 15px;
    display:inline;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
```

Check this  http://jsfiddle.net/ZHLKy/2/

Comment: this also works, but would then require `ol li ol` to have padding-left to be adjusted to line it up perfectly due to the difference in font-size.

Comment: issue with list-style: decimal inside;  is that the text in the content will wrap underneath the number.